# C#: how to set version number of assembly

Tags: c#, versioning

I have written a DLL in C# using VS2005.

Currently the DLL is showing a version number of 1.0.0.0.

How do I set this version number to something different?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can either specify the file version using the [AssemblyFileVersionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute.aspx) directly...

> Instructs a compiler to use a specific
>   version number for the Win32 file
>   version resource.

...or you can remove this attribute entirely which will mean that the file version defaults to the assembly version. This is probably good practice as having a file version that is different to the assembly version will cause confusion.

> If the AssemblyFileVersionAttribute is
>   not supplied, the
>   AssemblyVersionAttribute is used for
>   the Win32 file version that is
>   displayed on the Version tab of the
>   Windows file properties dialog.

You can set the assembly version using the [AssemblyVersionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx).

Assembly attributes are usually applied in the AssemblyInfo.cs file as stated in the other answers.

Comment: I just saw a good argument for not synchronizing the file and assembly versions...
http://freetodev.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!EC3C8F2028D842D5!1253.entry?wa=wsignin1.0&sa=191639258

Answer (score 32):

look in the AssemblyInfo.cs file for the following line, and set it to whatever version number you want:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: Very true, There is another way, I'm not sure about VS2005 but at least VS2008 and up has the properties item in the solution explorer, double-click it, it in  you also edit the assembly version

Comment: Can someone confirm whether this is possible in VS2005?

Comment: That is how to set the assembly version, yes. The properties item just sets the value in the assemblyinfo file.

Comment: Suppose we set it to 1.9.10292.8. But how to autoincrement it?

Answer (score 14):

To set it from Visual Studio's menus, without having to manually edit the file:

1. Right click on the project and click on **"Properties".**
2. Click on the **"Application" tab**.
3. Click on the **"Assembly Information" button**.
4. Specify the assembly version (it contains four text boxes, i.e., Major Version, Minor Version, Build Number, Revision).

It will store the assembly details in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file of the corresponding project.

Comment: This doesn't autofill the AssemblyVersion property in `AssemblyInfo.cs` for me in MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the version number in `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Note that the assembly version is not the same as the assembly file version. From your brief description it sounds more like you are looking for the latter - `AssemblyFileVersion`.

Comment: They're both likely to be the same, aren't they?

Comment: But how to autoincrement it? Please guide me

Answer (score 5):

Alter this line in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.9.10292.8")]
```

Comment: Suppose Now, I want to auto increment it from here on. I mean after next build it should be "1.9.10293" How to achieve that.

Comment: @Unbreakable you could write a console application that reads the AssemblyInfo.cs file into lines (`string[]`), looks for a line that starts with `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("`, parses the following substring until `")]` into a `new Version()`, increment the build, then replace the line with `[assembly: AssemblyVersion(\"" + myVersion.ToString() + "\")]` and write all lines back to the file.
You can call the application in Build Events (in your Project Properties), supplying the path using `$(ProjectDir)` to give your console app the project directory where to look for the AssemblyInfo file

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change it on visual studio open your solution file then right click and select properties then select Application on that select assembly information than change version on assembly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UG5U.png)