# UWP app package version set but the exe file shows 1.0.0.0 upon checking from task manager

Tags: uwp

I've been working on an UWP app lately. I've created app release package from VS 19 by using Publish -> create app packages -> sideloading -> signed and proceeded.

I set the version as 1.0.x.0 (1.0.1.0/1.0.2.0 . . . . ) in the package.appmanifest file as version too.

Upon installing from the created app package the app appears in the start menu.
From there I checked More -> App Settings
[image]

But when i run the app and check by the path below the runnable exe shows version 1.0.0.0

1. Run app -> Win key + X key -> Run Task Manager
2. App -> right-click -> Go to Details -> Select app.exe to right-click -> Properties -> Select Details

Can anyone help me on what i've been missing?

[image]

Here's a picture after the checking from task manager

Answer (score 1):

The properties window which you open from task manager shows properties of the executable file of your app. This file can have a different version than the application package.

If you are using.NET to create your executable file, you need to change [properties of the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975601/c-how-to-set-version-number-of-assembly) to change [File Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute.-ctor?view=net-5.0) and Product Version for the executable file.

[image]